# Odoo Configurations

Tags: customization, odoo

I installed Openerp7 and it worked good

then i put some add-ons then i returned me with handler not found..

Following errors in log file below are mentioned...

```
2014-09-06 17:43:16,509 3892 INFO openerp openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2014-09-06 17:43:17,994 3892 INFO openerp openerp.modules.loading: loading 46 modules...
2014-09-06 17:43:20,868 3892 INFO openerp openerp.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
2014-09-06 17:43:22,322 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:22] "GET /web/webclient/css?db=openerp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:25,562 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:25] "GET /web/webclient/js?db=openerp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:27,377 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:27] "POST /web/session/get_session_info HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:27,641 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:27] "POST /web/webclient/qweblist HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:27,857 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:27] "POST /web/webclient/bootstrap_translations HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:28,042 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:28] "POST /web/proxy/load HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:28,318 3892 ERROR ? openerp.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 440, in borrow
  File "psycopg2\__init__.pyc", line 178, in connect
OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

2014-09-06 17:43:28,318 3892 ERROR ? openerp.netsvc: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 122, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 359, in exp_list
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 484, in cursor
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 182, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 377, in _locked
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 440, in borrow
  File "psycopg2\__init__.pyc", line 178, in connect
OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

2014-09-06 17:43:28,325 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:28] "GET /web/binary/company_logo?session_id=9e63c8cabdc048c7aeb2f46f51a79830 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2014-09-06 17:43:28,469 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:28] "GET /web/static/src/img/logo2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:28,490 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:28] "POST /web/database/get_list HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:38,778 3892 INFO openerp openerp.service.web_services: successful login from 'admin' using database 'openerp'
2014-09-06 17:43:38,786 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:38] "POST /web/session/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:38,875 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:38] "POST /web/session/modules HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:39,214 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:39] "POST /web/webclient/csslist HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:39,224 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:39] "POST /web/webclient/qweblist HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:39,239 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:39] "POST /web/webclient/jslist HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:39,466 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:39] "GET /web/webclient/css?mods=web_diagram%2Cbase%2Cbase_setup%2Cmail%2Cboard%2Chr%2Cemail_template%2Cauth_signup%2Cshare%2Cportal%2Cprocess%2Cbase_calendar%2Ccrm%2Cportal_crm%2Cportal_hr_employees%2Chr_attendance%2Cweb_graph%2Cedi%2Caccount%2Caccount_voucher%2Csale%2Cweb_view_editor%2Cweb_calendar%2Chr_timesheet_sheet%2Cpoint_of_sale%2Cweb_gantt%2Caccount_accountant%2Cweb_tests%2Cstock HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:39,970 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:39] "POST /web/webclient/translations HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:39,979 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:39] "POST /web/proxy/load HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:40,009 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:40] "GET /web/static/lib/datejs/globalization/en-US.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:40,740 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:40] "GET /web/webclient/js?mods=web_diagram%2Cbase%2Cbase_setup%2Cmail%2Cboard%2Chr%2Cemail_template%2Cauth_signup%2Cshare%2Cportal%2Cprocess%2Cbase_calendar%2Ccrm%2Cportal_crm%2Cportal_hr_employees%2Chr_attendance%2Cweb_graph%2Cedi%2Caccount%2Caccount_voucher%2Csale%2Cweb_view_editor%2Cweb_calendar%2Chr_timesheet_sheet%2Cpoint_of_sale%2Cweb_gantt%2Caccount_accountant%2Cweb_tests%2Cstock HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:41,522 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:41] "GET /web/static/src/img/user_menu_avatar.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:41,829 3892 ERROR openerp openerp.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 440, in borrow
  File "psycopg2\__init__.pyc", line 178, in connect
OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

2014-09-06 17:43:41,854 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:41] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:41,865 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:41] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:42,036 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:42] "GET /web/binary/company_logo?session_id=9e63c8cabdc048c7aeb2f46f51a79830 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:42,269 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:42] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery.ui.bootstrap/css/custom-theme/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:42,424 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:42] "GET /web/binary/image?model=res.users&field=image_small&id=1&session_id=9e63c8cabdc048c7aeb2f46f51a79830 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:42,681 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:42] "GET /web/static/src/font/entypo-webfont.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:43,364 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:43] "POST /web/action/load HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:43,424 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:43] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:43,706 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:43] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:43,736 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:43] "GET /web/static/src/img/search_reset.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:43,757 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:43] "GET /web/static/src/font/mnmliconsv21-webfont.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:43,963 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:43] "POST /web/menu/load HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:44,010 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:44] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery.ui.bootstrap/css/custom-theme/images/ui-bg_glass_75_ffffff_1x400.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:44,029 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:44] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:44,130 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:44] "GET /hr_attendance/static/src/img/emp-out32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:44,181 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:44] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:44,421 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:44] "GET /hr_attendance/static/src/img/emp-in32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:44,427 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:44] "GET /web/static/src/img/view_empty_arrow.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:44,441 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:44] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:44,765 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:44] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:44,806 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:44] "GET /web/static/src/img/down-arrow.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:43:45,035 3892 INFO openerp werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:43:45] "POST /web/menu/load_needaction HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 17:44:02,540 3892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 17:44:02] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery.ui.bootstrap/css/custom-theme/images/ui-icons_f6cf3b_256x240.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-09-06 18:20:04,079 1636 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20140622-231040
2014-09-06 18:20:04,079 1636 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons
2014-09-06 18:20:04,079 1636 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2014-09-06 18:20:04,079 1636 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2014-09-06 18:20:04,079 1636 INFO ? openerp: database user: admin
2014-09-06 18:20:04,084 1636 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2014-09-06 18:20:04,084 1636 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named http
2014-09-06 18:20:04,084 1636 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\service\__init__.py", line 60, in load_server_wide_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 133, in load_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named http
2014-09-06 18:20:04,098 1636 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
2014-09-06 18:20:04,111 1636 INFO ? openerp.service.wsgi_server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2014-09-06 18:21:13,732 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:21:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:21:13,858 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:21:13] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:21:19,025 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:21:19] "GET /?ts=1409765540920 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:21:51,931 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:21:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:22:23,240 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:22:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:22:45,323 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:22:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:29:57,424 3436 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20140622-231040
2014-09-06 18:29:57,424 3436 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons
2014-09-06 18:29:57,424 3436 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2014-09-06 18:29:57,424 3436 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2014-09-06 18:29:57,424 3436 INFO ? openerp: database user: admin
2014-09-06 18:29:57,427 3436 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2014-09-06 18:29:57,427 3436 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named http
2014-09-06 18:29:57,427 3436 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\service\__init__.py", line 60, in load_server_wide_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 133, in load_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named http
2014-09-06 18:29:57,434 3436 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
2014-09-06 18:29:57,450 3436 INFO ? openerp.service.wsgi_server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2014-09-06 18:31:16,878 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:31:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:31:19,743 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:31:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:34:27,763 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:34:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:37:56,982 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:37:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:55:50,635 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:55:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:58:14,315 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:58:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:58:15,607 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:58:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:58:16,848 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:58:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:58:52,470 1636 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 18:58:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 18:59:48,960 2368 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20140622-231040
2014-09-06 18:59:48,960 2368 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons
2014-09-06 18:59:48,960 2368 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2014-09-06 18:59:48,961 2368 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2014-09-06 18:59:48,961 2368 INFO ? openerp: database user: admin
2014-09-06 18:59:48,964 2368 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2014-09-06 18:59:48,964 2368 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named http
2014-09-06 18:59:48,964 2368 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\service\__init__.py", line 60, in load_server_wide_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 133, in load_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named http
2014-09-06 18:59:48,971 2368 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
2014-09-06 18:59:49,016 2368 INFO ? openerp.service.wsgi_server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2014-09-06 19:00:02,701 2368 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 19:00:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 19:10:50,871 2368 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 19:10:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 19:30:41,278 2368 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 19:30:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 19:30:43,556 2368 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 19:30:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 19:30:44,753 2368 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 19:30:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 19:31:43,252 2368 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 19:31:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 19:31:58,799 2368 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 19:31:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-09-06 19:32:11,859 2368 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Sep/2014 19:32:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Please tell me about problems

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you have start with "Connection to the database failed", check your connection to the database.

Normally when I get the error "handler not found" is a problem with dependencies.

with the few information that you give is this what I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Connection to the database failed" is because the database connection is failing.

You could try:
/etc/init.d/postgresd restart

Or try connection:
sudo su postgres
psql
\l ; (For list databases)

Answer (score 0):

Did you manually killed a "db process" (not the openerp-server process) from the command line where it is showing the name of the database. If yes, then due to this you faced this issue.

You can do it restarting the openerp-server service  and restarting the postgressql service.

Hope this helps!!.